# How to play https video url using VideoView

Tags: https, android-videoview

> Getting MediaPlayer: error (1, -2147483648)

```
MediaController mediacontroller = new MediaController(getActivity());
mediacontroller.setAnchorView(videoView);
videoView.setVideoPath("https://example.com");
videoView.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

Class level variable

```
           VideoView videoView
```

I put this in OnCreate

```
             SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);
             videoView = FindViewById<VideoView>(Resource.Id.video);

             ImageButton button = FindViewById<ImageButton>(Resource.Id.two_btn);


            MediaController mController = new 
            Android.Widget.MediaController(this);
            mController.SetAnchorView(videoView);
            videoView.SetMediaController(mController);

            uriPath = "https://example.com";
            Android.Net.Uri uri = Android.Net.Uri.Parse(uriPath);
            videoView.RequestFocus();
            videoView.SetVideoURI(uri);
            videoView.Start();
```

Mine was in a button click event so I could start video with a button